# Joomla Admin panel showing error " JERROR_ALERTNOTEMPLATE You are not authorised to view this resource."

Tags: joomla

I have been using Joomla since an year ago. before few days, I made few changes to files, then the admin panel started showing error:

```
"JERROR_ALERTNOTEMPLATE You are not authorised to view this resource."
```

I am not able to figure out the solution.

Comment: In fact, i tried replacing the administrator folder from a backup. It did not work :-)\

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me start off with saying, that you should **NOT** edit core Joomla files for the following reasons:

1. They might get overridden during a Joomla update.
2. It might cause errors such as the one you currently have.
3. It might corrupt other functions.
4. It may cause security issues.

What I suggest you do is, download a fresh copy of Joomla, however only unzip the "administrator", "includes" and "libraries" folders. Then, upload these folders to the FTP so that they override the current ones.

Comment: I think you're probably on the right track. Based on [what I'm looking at](http://www.php.joomlademo.de/language/en-GB/en-GB.ini.source.txt),  that error text goes with JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR, not with JERROR_ALERTNOTEMPLATE. Suggests a corrupt file.